# Facebook Like Button is visible although being in a hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook-like

Since today i have the problem, that my facebook like button is showing on the page, although it is placed in a hidden div.
Every container down to the iframe containing the original facebook button has "visibility: none". The iframe itself is visible. Funny thing is, that the google share button works exactly the same (all containers down to the iframe are invis, and the iframe itself is visible) and is not showing.
The div containing my share buttons should change its visibility, when i hover over a ceartain area and, of course, with him the share buttons.
Works fine except for the facebook button.
Does anyone of you has experienced the same issue lately and/or has a solution for me?

Here is the code of my div containing the share buttons.

```
<div id="dachleiste-erweiterung-sm" class="socialmedia">
  {% set artikel_share = 0 %}
  <IR_INCLUDE FILE="tp_bks_snippet_share.twig" />
</div>
```

And this is the content of the tp_bks_snippet_share.twig

```
<div class="share col-md-30 clear clearfix">
  {% set artikel_share = "@@share{}@@" %}
  {% if artikel_share %}
    {% set share_url = url_canonical %}
  {% else %}
    {% set share_url = homepage_url %}
  {% endif %}

    {# https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ #}
  <div class="facebook float-left">
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="{{ share_url }}" data-width="100" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>
  </div>

    {# http://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons #}
  <div class="twitter float-left">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="{{ share_url }}" data-lang="de">Twittern</a>
    <script>!function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
      }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");</script>
  </div>

   {# https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/
    Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render. #}
  <div {% if artikel_share == 0 %}id="google_global" {% endif %}class="google float-left">
    <div class="g-plusone float-left" data-size="medium" data-href="{{ share_url }}"></div>
  </div>

    {# https://dev.xing.com/plugins/share_button/ #}
  <div class="xing float-left">
    <div data-counter="right" data-type="XING/Share" data-url="{{ share_url }}" data-lang="de"></div>
    <script>;
      (function(d, s) {
        var x = d.createElement(s),
                s = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        x.src = "https://www.xing-share.com/js/external/share.js";
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(x, s);
      })(document, "script");</script>
  </div>

  <div class="linkedIn float-left">
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
      lang: de_DE
    </script>
    <script type="IN/Share" data-url="{{ share_url }}"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course i could try something like setting the opacity of the facebook button to 0 or stuff like that, but i would like to find a better solution.

Any help is appreciated.
Maverick

Comment: I think set a hidden FB like button is against their TOS. Some JS should force it to be visible. Maybe setting instead an absolutely positioned element would work but be aware of FB TOS

Comment: check CSS by inspecting element and check if there is something like visibility:visible !important. Facebook and google uses there own js to style everything. To hide visibility, you should use `visibility:hidden !important` in your stylesheet

Comment: I just used the solution you recommended @A.Wolff and positioned the container absolute to hide and show it on hover.
If you want you can add your comment as answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: @A.Wolff can you cite any reference for this? I don't doubt you and this would def. be the kind of crappy thing face***k would do, but I could not find that policy with a quick google.

Comment: @artfulrobot i've quickly searched and found this: "You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin." https://developers.facebook.com/policy/ But better would be to ask them directly if it is allowed to set a FB like button hidden

Comment: Thanks. I'm not v familiar with Facebook.  We've got ours in a pop open thing at side. Turned it off completely at mo because it was obscuring content!

Answer (score 2):

Encountered same issue. I have FB Like button placed in a hidden container which i want to display only on button click. However about a week ago FB Like button became always visible.

I'm not sure how Facebook did it before, but now the iframe containing FB Like button has own CSS property ***'visibility:visible'***, which makes the button visible even if parent container has ***'visibility:hidden'*** set.

Using ***'display:none', 'display:block'*** instead of ***'visibility:hidden', 'visibility:visible'*** on your parent div should solve the problem.

In my case i can use only ***'visibility'*** property so as a solution i use following jQuery code and call it on document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setFBLikeVisibility();
});

function setFBLikeVisibility(){
    if(typeof($('div.fb-like').html()) != 'undefined'){

        if($('div.fb-like iframe').css('visibility') == 'visible'){
            $('div.fb-like iframe').css('visibility', 'inherit');
            /* or $('div.fb-like iframe').css('visibility', ''); */
        } else {
            setTimeout('setFBLikeVisibility()', 100);
        }
     }
}
```

This sets CSS style '**visibility:inherit**' to the iframe containing Like button, thus making it show/hide according to parent container visibility. Function is recursive because, after some testing, i noticed that it could take some time after page load until the Like button is loaded and becomes visible.